# Xcode 4 - build output directory

Tags: ide, xcode4

I have problems with setting up/locating my output files in Xcode4 (beta 5). They are placed somewhere in `~/Library/Developer/ugly_path/...`. I can't even select "show in finder" on my products. It is the same for a simple C project, Foundation tool and even Cocoa bundle. A Debugging works fine.

Could you please point me out where and how to set up / build output directories? (I know it sounds dumb, I've been coding in Xcode3 for months, but I can't figure it out in Xcode4 beta).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 344, accepted):

From the Xcode menu on top, click preferences, select the locations tab, look at the build location option.

You have 2 options:

1. Place build products in derived data location (recommended)
2. Place build products in locations specified by targets

Update:
On xcode 4.6.2 you need to click the advanced button on the right side below the derived data text field. Build Location select legacy.

Comment: This answer explains why this change was made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331270/why-doesnt-xcode-4-create-any-products

Comment: Proud Member, what do you mean these are not in Xcode 5? They are in Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data -> Advanced.

Comment: Ok, so my build goes into the `.../XCode/DerivedData/` folder, simple enough.  Except that the subfolders seem to be `AppName-asdflkjqwergoobledygook`.  Since I'm building from a script, I'd like to actually *find* the build (so I can package it and send via TestFlight :)  How do I determine which of the many `MyAppName-xxxx`-s is the right one?  Thanks!

Comment: @Olie You can also change the derived data location to a path of your own choosing

Comment: @Gerard: I could, but that's not what I want to do.  I'm checking out sources from a repo, then building via command line, and I want to know where the build went.  It would be inappropriate for my build-script to modify the project in any way (say, by changing the project settings.)

Answer (score 141):

If you build from command line, you can set output directory in the following way:

```
xcodebuild -workspace 'WORKSPACE_NAME.xcworkspace' \
           -scheme 'SCHEME_NAME' \
           -configuration 'Release' \
           -sdk iphoneos7.0 CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='OUTPUT_DIRECTORY'
```

Comment: To make my sh scripts working I needed to remove single quotes and write just CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/...

Comment: @occulus, you're absolutely right as this will fail building the testing target after building the project, I think if you're just building it MIGHT be okay, but better use absolute paths !

Comment: In case anyone else is trying to solve a similar problem I convinced XCode 6.x to place the  linked binary *exactly* where it was needed using this combination: ```/Users/moi/src/mozbuilds/xul3604/$(CONFIGURATION)/dist/bin```

Answer (score 30):

In Xcode 5: **Xcode** menu > **Preferences...** item > **Locations** tab > **Locations** sub-tab > **Advanced...** button > **Custom** option.

Then choose, e.g., **Relative to Workspace**.

Comment: May you live to be a hundred years old, strong, and healthy sir. *Thank you*!

Answer (score 13):

If you have Xcode 4 Build Location setting set to "Place build products in derived data location (recommended), it should be located in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. This directory will have your project in there as a directory, the project name will be appended with a bunch of generated letters so look carefully.

Answer (score 10):

Keep derived data but use the DSTROOT to specify the destination.

Use DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION to force deployment.

Use the undocumented DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH to copy the dSYM over too.

This allows you to use derived data location from xcodebuild and not have to do wacky stuff to find the app.

```
xcodebuild -sdk "iphoneos" -workspace Foo.xcworkspace -scheme Foo -configuration "Debug" DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES DSTROOT=tmp DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=tmp build
```

Answer (score 8):

You can always find the build directory by looking in the build log viewer, and copying the path there into a terminal window.

I use this to analyze my iOS .app bundles before they get installed to make sure no stray files are being included.

Comment: And where do I find this build log?? Searching for "build log" in Xcode help returns 0 results.

Comment: Nm, found the "Log Navigator", which looks like a speech bubble.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who wants to find the build directory from a script but does not want to change it, run the following to get a list of all the build settings that point to a folder in DerivedData:

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | grep DerivedData
```

If you run custom targets and schemes, please put them there as well:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "Foo.xcworkspace" -scheme "Bar" -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug -showBuildSettings | grep DerivedData
```

Look at the output to locate the setting output that you want and then:

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | grep SYMROOT | cut -d "=" -f 2 - | sed 's/^ *//'
```

The last part cuts the string at the equal sign and then trims the whitespace at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the new Xcode4 Workspaces, you can change the *Derived Data Location* under **File** -> **Workspace settings...**

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the output directory using the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` environment variable.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH1-SW1

Comment: no that's unrelated to the derived location / legacy (per target) location behavior

Comment: Yes it is. It works either way. From the documentation: "Directory path. Identifies the directory under which all build-related files for the active build configuration are placed."

Comment: nope. not with xcode4 it depends on `Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived data` setting as explained in the most voted answer. + the document you're referring to was last updated in 2010

Comment: I've actually used this setting to configure the build directory with xcode4 from xcodebuild.  Give it a try.

Comment: well I've tried with Xcode 4.3.1 (from the IDE) and without changing the global setting, products are build somewhere in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and not inside the directory I specify with `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`. If I want `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` to be honored, I have to switch Xcode derived data preferences to "Legacy"

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check before you start playing with Xcode preferences is:

Select your target and go to **Build Settings > Packaging > Wrapper Extension**

The value there should be: **app**

If not double click it and type "app" without the qoutes.

Answer (score -1):

This was so annoying. Open your project, click on Target, Open Build Phases tab. Check your Copy Bundle Resources for any red items.