# Xcode 4.5.2 errors are found but Build is marked as Succeeded

Tags: xcode, build, compiler-errors

This problem is very similar to this one: [Xcode 4 Preview 4 displays "Build Succeeded" but with errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360558/xcode-4-preview-4-displays-build-succeeded-but-with-errors)

The different solutions proposed at the link doesn't work. I tried using product clean, deleteing the Derived Data, restart XCode and the Mac, but the problem still appears.

It seems that all the error are linked to the project's precompiled header : although the PCH is working fine and has no error in itself, the errors reported look like the pch is not  found for this specific file. 
Also sometimes, while the build progresses, the errors appear and disappear randomly. Anyone have an idea on this?

[image]

The error only appear in the file(s) opened in the editor. If I close the file's in xcode but keep the project open, then no error are reported at all.

Comment: A screenshot or copy of the error might help. Otherwise, you could try and modify the pch file so that it will detect the change and re-compile it, possibly clearing any errors you might have for good.

Comment: The errors are mostly "Use of undeclared identifier XXX", and the XXX identifier is defined in the pch using #define

Comment: You're assuming that the .pch file is found/fine. Try putting in an explicit '#warning "This is BAD!"' in your .pch file and then re-compile. If you don't get the warning then Xcode isn't finding your .pch file.

Comment: The constants defined in the pch are used all over the project, and the project builds and run completely fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning the build folder?

In XCode, open the Product menu then hold down option. Clean should change to Clean Build Folder.

Edit:

You can also press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Tried that immediately, did not work. This problem is chasing two of my projects.  Shows same "not defined" error in both projects for the same header file that is clearly included.  This happened out of the blue, no changes to system or to compiler install.

Comment: Wow, this worked for me. I've been using Xcode for years and never knew about this. I just restart Xcode. The discoverability of this secret key mapping is terrible!

Answer (score 68):

Cleaning, closing, restarting - none worked for me.

A simple touch/edit to the pch file in question resolved the issue.

Comment: This, surprisingly, is what worked for me... in XCode 5.0.1 :(

Comment: This is absolutely true.. By some reason the file does not get compiled or something

Comment: This is the fix. In addition, in Xcode 5.x you can force a recompile of the xxx-Prefix.pch by selecting it in Xcode and running Product > Perform Action > Compile "xxx-Prefix.pch".

Comment: Worked for me too.. in XCODE 6.1!!

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue, and neither types of cleans helped. I also tried deleting the build folder, restarting xcode, etc and for me what finally solved the issue was to remove the files that the errors referenced and re-add them.

Additionally, I investigated the error after the fact, and the issue seems to be XCode's "Show Live Issues" feature. (This can be unchecked in the preferences, this also solved the issue but was unsatisfactory as a solution as I've grown to enjoy xcode's live code sense.)

Comment: I couldn't just re-add all the files since so many were affected, but unchecking "Show live issues" in Xcode prefs fixed the issue. I'd rather have issues not show up until I build than have dozens of fake ones hanging around all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning the product folder and restarting didn't help me. I started seeing this after I deleted the DerivedData folder. I was able to "fix" by doing :

1. Clean build.
2. Archive
3. Build

Comment: Archive helped me too. XCode started to glitch after I did `pod update`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure adding a define to the pch will work as you think. Try creating a Constants header and add your defines there. Then you can include the import statement in your pch file and it should work that way.

Comment: the pch does just that, importing other .h with defines. This worked fine until one day it started seeing errors which dont exist. I found out that the only fake errors it sees are in the opened file.

Answer (score 1):

```
Go to xcode install folder like below.
```

/Users/vinod/Library/Developer/Xcode

Step-1 Quit the xcode

Step-2 Delete the DerivedData Folder

Step-3 Now open the project and clean it all issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

to add my two cents: my solution was to slightly change the order of imports in the pch file.

Maybe this is related to simply edit the file, but I've tried to "touch" it and edit and the only "thing" that did fix the problem was to move some import before others.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete derived data
2. Clean project
3. Quit Xcode and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the last #import from .pch file, build the app then putting it back and building it again did the trick for me.

If you still see the errors then you could repeat this step for last two imports, last three imports and so on.