# XCode reports error lines in editor but still launches app with no errors

Tags: ios, xcode

I can launch my app on the simulator and device.

XCode shows errors in many places in code which in reality are not errors - such as "class wasn't found" or "method doesn't exist"

Tried restarted XCode, cleaning project and deleting derived data but still not working. Erroneous errors are still reported.

Comment: Is there any common factor in which items show errors...location of the .h files that declare them, for example?  I've had this when I've used explicit include locations like `#import <SubFolder/header.h>` that weren't part of the project's header search path.

Comment: Also, are they possibly old errors? I've seen cases where Xcode just won't let go of older errors and keeps showing them to me over and over.

Comment: No - it just started happening . I saw many similar posts and tried many of the proposed resolutions - finally touching the .pch file (added a space) - it worked in XCodes mysterious ways and the errors disappeared

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 4.5.2 errors are found but Build is marked as Succeeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954229/xcode-4-5-2-errors-are-found-but-build-is-marked-as-succeeded)

Answer (score 0):

Touch the .PCH file.  added a "space" and the "errors" disappeared

Seems to be a bug with the XCode code-sense