# Xcode builds the target successfully even if there are random errors

Tags: xcode, macos, build, xcode4

I have working on an Xcode project where things were going correctly. Then, out of the blue, Xcode started behaving strangely. I introduced an error in the project, but Xcode says: *Build succeeded*! Then, I added some random words in the code, still Xcode compiled it correctly.

What could be the reason for Xcode to malfunction? I also tried both the answers mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360558/xcode-4-preview-4-displays-build-succeeded-but-with-errors) post, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure you were building the correct target (i.e. one that used the source files you were introducing errors into)?

Comment: Yes. But, I also suspect the reason may somehow be related to me changing the time of my machine. But, I had deleted all the artifacts also. I tried clean-build, which worked. But, now I am unable to see the errors, Xcode says "Build failed", but does not display where the errors are.

Comment: In addition to Trojanfoe’s suggestion, are you sure the file you are editing is still in the project? Check the file inspector.

Comment: I have had the same problem. Sometimes shutting down everything and restarting the computer will fix the problem. Sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to this directory

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

And deleting your project.

As a side note when you open a window in finder you can hold command + shift and press G to open a dialog box to copy the path into. Just in case you didn't know.