# Xcode doesn't create iOS .app release file (products). How to fix this?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, release

I've updated to the latest version of Xcode 4.5.1 and I have some troubles. When I build debug version of the project and run it on iOS simulator everything works just fine. But when I switched to release flavour in project schema and build project nothing happened. I mean project runs on simulator, but `Build` folder of my project remains empty.

I tried to follow this advice
[Why doesn't Xcode 4 create any products?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331270/why-doesnt-xcode-4-create-any-products)

but in the created folder `DerivedData` there are only logs and indexes folders and no .app files.
So the question is:  How to get executable on real iOS6 device `.app` file in Xcode 4.5.1? I'm really a newbie and the delivery/deployment process in iOS is unknown to me.

Answer (score 4):

Change your choice of deployment devices to an actual iOS device (don't use the simulator).  After that, execute an "Archive" build (Product -> Archive).  This option will be grayed out if you don't choose to deploy to an actual iOS device.

Comment: can you plz elaborate your answer and explain a bit more...thanxs