# Choose where to place .app file for xcode build

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there anyway to choose where to place the XCode build (.app and  dSYM files).

I want to place the .app and the dSYM file in a folder together with the XCode project.

Is there any way to do this other than manually moving the files?

Comment: OK, on further searching, these links helped me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233581/xcode-4-build-output-directory

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331270/why-doesnt-xcode-4-create-any-products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/Build/Build.html) 
it may be useful
Also

[Xcode 4 - build output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233581/xcode-4-build-output-directory)

Comment: Thank you, I just came across it myself.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, try **Preferences->Locations->Derived Data**

Click on the `Derived Data` pull down and pick Custom