# How to delete build folder in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

How to delete build folder in  xcode 4 in order to reduce the size of the application directory?
Its difficult to send entire workspcace in mails if its built in Xcode 4.
Any other practices for reducing the size of the xcode 4 workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all the build data for all your projects into one folder as per [Xcode 4 - build output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233581/xcode-4-build-output-directory/4282467#4282467). This way you will not bloat your project folders with unnecessary compiled data. The you just zip your folders and sent the archives without having to delete the build folders.

On the other hand the best practice is to use an svn or git source tree to share your data with other developers. You never commit your binary data to the repo of course, just the code and optionally Xcode data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you share the links to learn how to setup git repository for xcode 4 in order to share code in a team?

Comment: Sure. Start with the official git web site to check if it fits your needs: http://git-scm.com/ . You could start with a sample project follow Creating and Commiting. Then depending on your resources etc you should create a git clone on a remote server and push your changes there. Have a look at http://engineeredweb.com/blog/10/2/building-your-own-git-server if you need a "server" solution. I personally use redmine for project management with a gitolite setup and multiple git repos. Also you will probably like to use a visual client http://stackoverflow.com/q/455698/171711

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the build folder in Finder without causing any problems.

As for other strategies to reduce size, I would just make sure there are no unused files still lurking in your folder (old images, classes, etc.)