# Problems using .open with ifsteam objects

Tags: c++, io

The best way to explain my problem is probably just to show you my code, because it's as simple as it gets.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    std::ifstream in;
    std::string line;
    in.open("test.txt");
    if (in.fail()) std::cout << "failed. \n";
    getline(in, line);
    std::cout << line;

    return 0;
}
```

So when I run this, console is returning "failed." instead of opening up the file called test.txt — which is in the same folder as my .xcodeproj file and is also displayed in my Xcode navigator.

I'm not sure what I'm misunderstanding about this process, but I suspect it will be something simple.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is in the same directory as your .xcodeproj file? Well, there's your problem right here.

By default, the working directory of a process launched from Xcode will be the output directory (that is, the directory where the program is). Depending on your Xcode version, it's  probably going to be in `<Project Directory>/build/Debug`.

Try moving the file there.

Comment: Woohoo! This was the solution, thanks!

The folder name ended up being:
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project_dir/Build/Products/Debug

Comment: Found a good reference on creating output directories in Xcode 4:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233581/xcode-4-build-output-directory