# Xcode 4.2 product location

Tags: xcode, binary, location, xcode4.2

I can't make Xcode change the location of my product to

~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/

It places it in the DerivedData folder, How can I change it??

Thanks you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4282467/925976) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4555629/925976) answer what can be a solution for you. As a workaround, the [build setting preferences](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW51) should be edited in your project.