# Creating static libraries: how to change the target location?

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

How can I change the target location of a static library in xCode ?

Right now it is built in the OSX system iOS developer library, but I would like to change it to a location inside my project directory

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change from build settings tab. I do not have Xcode with me right now so I cannot post a picture, but it should not be too hard to find. Click on the project file and look at the build settings tab.

Comment: I can only change headers path from there, but not products location. If you can check with your xCode later, it would be helpful

Comment: I have found a similar question. It should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233581/xcode-4-build-output-directory