# In Xcode, when compiling c++, where does the file stream output the file?

Tags: c++, xcode5.1

I know that in VS2012, the fout thing is saved in the same folder as the source.cpp file, but I cannot find the file in mac using Xcode. 
Let me be clear:

```
    int main()
    {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("MyFile.txt");   
    fout << "Where am I going?";
    fout.close();
    return 0;
    }
```

so if "MyFile.txt" does not exist, it is created. then I don't know where it goes...

Comment: Doing VS for ages, I've never came across a "four thing" in VS.NET. What are you refering to?

Comment: OK :-), then my follow-up question is: What is a "fout thing"?

Comment: well, let me edit my question......

Comment: Maybe you are refering to the [build output directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233581/xcode-4-build-output-directory)?

Comment: I don't know if that's what i'm asking...just edited my question. i'm really a beginner to c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your home (ex. /Users/roshinichi) follow this path

```
./Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

here are located your application "derived data". Your file is there.
In general, on mac, you can run from a shell

```
find . -name MyFile.txt
```

I hope this can help you.